# re.split(), как добавить в качестве разделителя '/|*|-|+'

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.11

Пишу калькулятор на Python.

Понадобилось сделать проценты, искал решение, что-то нашёл связанное с циклом for, но с умножение работает не верно. Придумал, как это сделать с re.split(): разбить строку на числа, узнаем нужный процент и подставляем вместо самого числа с процентами. То беж по такому принципу:

```
# Пусть self.ui.lineEdit.text() = '200+50'
text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
# Нажал на кнопку процента
elements = re.split('/|*|-|+', text)
# Отсюда elements = ['200', '50.0']
elements[-1] = str(float(elements[-2])/100*float(elements[-1]))
text = ''
for i in elements:
    text = text + i
# text = '200+50.0
# Далее нажимаю '=' и получаю значение 250 (в теории).
# Но тут проблема: нельзя разделить строку символами + - / *
# Если попытаться, то получаешь ошибку.
```

re.split() выдаёт ошибку при нажатии на кнопку %, если разделять строку другими знаками: пробел, тире, запятая и т.д, тогда строка разделится без всяких ошибок.

Если же у вас есть другое решение проблемы с процентами, то тоже буду благодарен.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\Calculator\main.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    self.ui.pushButton_percent.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('%', 'percent'))
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Projects\Calculator\main.py", line 76, in entrance
    elements = re.split(r'+-/*', text)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sdodx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 206, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sdodx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 294, in _compile
    p = _compiler.compile(pattern, flags)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sdodx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\_compiler.py", line 743, in compile
    p = _parser.parse(p, flags)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sdodx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\_parser.py", line 980, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sdodx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\_parser.py", line 455, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sdodx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\_parser.py", line 682, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
```

Хелп. А, ну, ещё вдобавок и не работает удаление '.0' (def format_needless) в конце числа, но это уже второстепенно - как-нибудь справлюсь.
Вот весь код:
`main.py`

```
import sys
import math
import re
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QWidget)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Функционал
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.error_status = False
        
        self.ui.pushButton_percent.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('%', 'percent'))
        self.ui.pushButton_cleanEntrance.clicked.connect(self.cleanEntrance)
        self.ui.pushButton_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear)
        self.ui.pushButton_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        self.ui.pushButton_fraction.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('1/', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_square.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('²'))
        self.ui.pushButton_squareRoot.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('√', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_divide.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('/'))
        self.ui.pushButton_seven.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('7'))
        self.ui.pushButton_eight.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('8'))
        self.ui.pushButton_nine.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('9'))
        self.ui.pushButton_multiply.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('*'))
        self.ui.pushButton_four.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('4'))
        self.ui.pushButton_five.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('5'))
        self.ui.pushButton_six.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('6'))
        self.ui.pushButton_minus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('-'))
        self.ui.pushButton_one.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('1'))
        self.ui.pushButton_two.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('2'))
        self.ui.pushButton_three.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('3'))
        self.ui.pushButton_plus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('+'))
        self.ui.pushButton_negate.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('-', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_zero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('0'))
        self.ui.pushButton_point.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('.'))
        self.ui.pushButton_equal.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

    def clear(self):
        # Очистка
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('0')
        self.format()

    def cleanEntrance(self):
        # Чистый вход
        self.clear()

    def delete(self):
        # Удаление
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        text = text[:len(text)-1]
        if len(text) == 0:
            text = '0'
        self.format()
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)

    def entrance(self, symbol, type = None):
        # Ввод
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if self.error_status == True:
            self.clear()
            self.error_status = False
        if type != None:
            if type == 'special':
                text = symbol + '(' + text + ')'
            else:
               elements = re.split(r'+-/*', text)
               print(elements)
        else:
            if text == '0':
                text = ''
            text = text + symbol
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)
        self.format()

    def format(self):
        # Форматирование
        self.format_font()
        self.format_length()
        self.format_needless()

    def format_font(self):
        # Форматирование шрифта
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if len(text) > 11:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 24pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
            if len(text) > 14:
                self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 20pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
                if len(text) > 17:
                    self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 18pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
        else:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 30pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)

    def format_length(self):
        # Уменьшение длины выражения
        pass

    def format_needless(self):
        # Удаление '.0' в конце числа
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if text[len(text)-2] + text[len(text)-1] == '.0':
            text = str(math.trunc(int(text)))
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)

    def calculate(self):
        # Счёт
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        text = text.replace('√', 'math.sqrt')
        text = text.replace('²', '**2')
        print(text)
        try:
            result = str(eval(text))
            text = result
        except:  
            text = "Ошибка"
            self.error_status = True
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)
        self.format()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`ui_main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'ui_main.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.5.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QWidget)
import assets_rc

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamilies([u"Noto Sans SC"])
        font.setPointSize(11)

#       icon = QIcon()
#       icon.addFile(u":/assets/assets/icon.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        MainWindow.resize(330, 470)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(330, 470))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(330, 470))
#       MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"font: 11pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.layoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(u"layoutWidget")
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 170, 311, 291))

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)

        self.pushButton_percent = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_percent.setObjectName(u"pushButton_percent")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_percent.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_percent.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.setObjectName(u"pushButton_cleanEntrance")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_clear = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_clear.setObjectName(u"pushButton_clear")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_clear.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_clear.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_delete = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_delete.setObjectName(u"pushButton_delete")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_delete.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_delete.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_fraction = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_fraction.setObjectName(u"pushButton_fraction")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_fraction.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_fraction.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_square = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_square.setObjectName(u"pushButton_square")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_square.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_square.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_squareRoot = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_squareRoot.setObjectName(u"pushButton_squareRoot")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_squareRoot.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_squareRoot.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_divide = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_divide.setObjectName(u"pushButton_divide")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_divide.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_divide.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_multiply = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_multiply.setObjectName(u"pushButton_multiply")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_multiply.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_multiply.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_minus = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_minus.setObjectName(u"pushButton_minus")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_minus.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_minus.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_plus = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_plus.setObjectName(u"pushButton_plus")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_plus.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_plus.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_equal = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_equal.setObjectName(u"pushButton_equal")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_equal.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_equal.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_point = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_point.setObjectName(u"pushButton_point")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_point.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_point.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_negate = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_negate.setObjectName(u"pushButton_negate")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_negate.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_negate.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_zero = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_zero.setObjectName(u"pushButton_zero")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_zero.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_zero.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_one = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_one.setObjectName(u"pushButton_one")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_one.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_one.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_two = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_two.setObjectName(u"pushButton_two")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_two.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_two.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_three = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_three.setObjectName(u"pushButton_three")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_three.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_three.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_four = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_four.setObjectName(u"pushButton_four")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_four.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_four.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_five = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_five.setObjectName(u"pushButton_five")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_five.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_five.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_six = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_six.setObjectName(u"pushButton_six")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_six.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_six.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_seven = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_seven.setObjectName(u"pushButton_seven")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_seven.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_seven.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_eight = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_eight.setObjectName(u"pushButton_eight")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_eight.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_eight.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        
        self.pushButton_nine = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_nine.setObjectName(u"pushButton_nine")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_nine.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_nine.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(10, 70, 311, 91))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 30pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
        self.lineEdit.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(21)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_percent, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_cleanEntrance, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_clear, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_delete, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_fraction, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_square, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_squareRoot, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_divide, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_seven, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_eight, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_nine, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_multiply, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_four, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_five, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_six, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_minus, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_one, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_two, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_three, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_plus, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_negate, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_zero, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_point, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_equal, 5, 3, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041a\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043a\u0443\u043b\u044f\u0442\u043e\u0440", None))
        self.pushButton_point.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u",", None))
        self.pushButton_negate.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00b1"))
        self.pushButton_equal.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"=", None))
        self.pushButton_divide.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00f7", None))
        self.pushButton_three.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None))
        self.pushButton_multiply.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00d7", None))
        self.pushButton_six.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None))
        self.pushButton_plus.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+", None))
        self.pushButton_seven.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None))
        self.pushButton_fraction.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1/x", None))
        self.pushButton_nine.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None))
        self.pushButton_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"C", None))
        self.pushButton_squareRoot.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00b2\u221ax", None))
        self.pushButton_four.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None))
        self.pushButton_zero.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
        self.pushButton_one.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None))
        self.pushButton_delete.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u232b", None))
        self.pushButton_eight.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None))
        self.pushButton_five.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None))
        self.pushButton_percent.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"%", None))
        self.pushButton_square.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"x\u00b2", None))
        self.pushButton_minus.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u2212", None))
        self.pushButton_two.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None))
        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"CE", None))
        self.lineEdit.setText('0')
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Не относится к вопросу, но не нужно разбирать выражения регулярками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` и `+` нужно экранировать, чтобы они не воспринимались, как управляющие символы повторения регулярок:

```py
elements = re.split('/|\*|-|\+', text)
```

Но ещё лучше использовать квадратные скобки для перечисления символов-разделителей:

```py
elements = re.split('[-/*+]', text)
```

P.S. С тире тоже не всё просто, спасибо за комментарии, перенёс его на первое место.

Comment: Спасибо, краш) <3

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, я в дороге, некогда следить за сообщениями )  Впредь если что-то такое будет, можете сами править ответ, я не против )

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
re.split('/|*|-|+', text)
```

используйте

```
re.split(r'[/*+-]', text)   # символ минус специальный, должен быть в начале или в конце
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Квадратные скобки значат совпадение с 1 символом, когда в строке встретится любой из символов в скобках.

---

*Что не так с вашей регуляркой?*

Проблема с вашим регулярным выражением состоит в том, что символы `+` и `*` являются в регулярках *специальными символами для повторений.*

Когда вам более нравится ваше регулярное выражение, следует перед этими символами вставить обратный слеш (`\`):

```
re.split('/|\*|-|\+', text)
```

Comment: Спасибо) <3 <3<3

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, спасибо, исправил (дал на конец, в начале или в конце класса `-` работает правильно).